# node.js server show user raw html code

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I am working on a simple server that stores files and lets you view them by typing the file name after the IP, e.g. if I want to see pic.jpg, I can go to
`192.168.1.88:8000/pic.jpg` and it will show you pic.png, showing the picture works fine, but I also want my server to show raw source code of html files, I tried by seting the server to think its a .txt file, but the browser still shows the page and not the code, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Content-Type` header as `text/plain` and browser will show the raw html instead of parsing it.

Comment: I tried it, the browser itself sees that the file follows html code rules, so it shows the page

Comment: @MichaelKiselev are you sure you set the Content-Type header, the browser is not supposed to parse it if so. Check with curl...

Comment: @MichaelKiselev hello try setting Content-Type to `text/plain; charset=utf-8`.

Comment: yes, I did it correctly, and tested it on both Chromium and Firefox, and it still did not work

Comment: @MichaelKiselev see my comment.

Comment: I just checked, did not work, sorry for wasting your time with my problem

Comment: Maybe it is that I use Firefox on Ubuntu